# Remove icon-calendar from displaying from entire Joomla website?

Tags: joomla-3.x, icon

Is there a way to remove the icon-calendar from displaying throughout the entire Joomla website, without having to do an override on a bunch of .php files? Could this be done with CSS? Or possibly changing the that font to be 1x1 pixels in size?

Comment: `.icon-calendar { display: none }`?

Comment: @Lodder Thanks, but while that removes the image icon from appearing, the reserved space for it is still there. I'm not a CSS wizard.

Comment: A link to the website will probably help.

Comment: @NeilRobertson Wish I could do that, but it's on an intranet.